# Pandas: Adding a new column with random numbers to DF based on multiple criteria from row

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner.  I've looked all over and read a bunch of related questions but can't quite figure this out.  I know I am the problem and that I'm missing something, but I'm hoping someone will be kind and help me out.  I am attempting to convert data from one video game (a college basketball simulation) into data consistent with another video game's (pro basketball simulation) format.

I have a DF that has columns:
Name, Pos, Height, Weight, Shot, Points

With values such as:
Jon Smith, C, 84, 235, Exc, 19.4
Greg Jones, PG, 72, 187, Fair, 12.0

I want create a new column for "InsideScoring".  What I'd like to do is assign a player a randomly generated number within a certain range based on what position they played, height, weight, shot rating and points scored.

I tried a bunch of attempts like:

```
df1['InsideScoring'] = 0
df1.loc[(df1.Pos == "C") &
        (df1.Height > 82) &
        (df1.Points > 19.0) &
        (df1.Weight > 229), 'InsideScoring'] = np.random.randint(85,100)
```

When I do this, all the players (row at column "InsideScoring") that meet the criteria get assigned the same value between 85 and 100 rather than a random mix of numbers between 85 and 100.

Eventually, what I want to do is go through the list of players and based on those four criteria, assign values from different ranges.  Any ideas appreciated.

[Pandas: Create a new column with random values based on conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112874/pandas-create-a-new-column-with-random-values-based-on-conditional)

[Numpy "where" with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use `np.select` here.  You set up your conditions, your outputs, and you're good to go.  However, to avoid iteration, but *also* to avoid assigning the same random value to every column that meets the condition, create random values equal to the length of your DataFrame, and select from those:

---

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Chris', 'John'],
    'Height': [72, 84],
    'Pos': ['PG', 'C'],
    'Weight': [165, 235], 
    'Shot': ['Amazing', 'Fair'],
    'Points': [999, 25]
})

    Name  Height Pos  Weight     Shot  Points
0  Chris      72  PG     165  Amazing     999
1   John      84   C     235     Fair      25
```

---

Now set up your ranges and your conditions (Create as many of these as you like):

```
cond1 = df.Pos.eq('C') & df.Height.gt(80) & df.Weight.gt(200)
cond2 = df.Pos.eq('PG') & df.Height.lt(80) & df.Weight.lt(200)

range1 = np.random.randint(85, 100, len(df))
range2 = np.random.randint(50, 85, len(df))

df.assign(InsideScoring=np.select([cond1, cond2], [range1, range2]))
```

```
    Name  Height Pos  Weight     Shot  Points  InsideScoring
0  Chris      72  PG     165  Amazing     999             72
1   John      84   C     235     Fair      25             89
```

Now to verify this doesn't assign values more than once:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*5)

... # Setup the ranges and conditions again

df.assign(InsideScoring=np.select([cond1, cond2], [range1, range2]))
```

```
    Name  Height Pos  Weight     Shot  Points  InsideScoring
0  Chris      72  PG     165  Amazing     999             56
1   John      84   C     235     Fair      25             96
0  Chris      72  PG     165  Amazing     999             74
1   John      84   C     235     Fair      25             93
0  Chris      72  PG     165  Amazing     999             63
1   John      84   C     235     Fair      25             97
0  Chris      72  PG     165  Amazing     999             55
1   John      84   C     235     Fair      25             95
0  Chris      72  PG     165  Amazing     999             60
1   John      84   C     235     Fair      25             90
```

And we can see that random values are assigned, even though they all match one of two conditions.  While this is less memory efficient than iterating and picking a random value, since we are creating a lot of unused numbers, it will still be faster as these are vectorized operations.

Comment: I tested it on a sample DF and it worked, so I think this is what I needed to understand.  Thanks.  However, when I tested it on the actual dataframe it gave me either: ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape or ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (80640,) (105,).  If you have any idea how I messed that up let me know ... but thank you, your answer is what I needed to know.

Comment: Did you forget to re-run your `conds` and `ranges` setup?  You have to re-run that each time or else the ranges will be the incorrect shape

Comment: Yes.  It now works.  My lack of reputation prevents me from +1-ing your answer, but I really appreciate the help.  This was really stumping me.

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!